# hook_civicrm_post - on creating event cannot update the record in `civicrm_event` table

Tags: wordpress, civievent, database

I have a custom field in `civicrm_event` table which I want to update on creating event. However the hook_civicrm_post on creating event cannot update the record in `civicrm_event` table due to database transaction lock still in place at that point. Is this possible to be achieved with another database transaction? Can someone give me an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See custom fields, See custom fields 
http://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/events/custom-data-for-events/